# How do I make a timer in pygame without delaying the program

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a pygame game and need the variable "img" to cycle through multiple slides to make a walking animation, but all the timers i can find made with python/pygame delay the program which i don't want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move an object every few seconds in Pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368999/move-an-object-every-few-seconds-in-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

You can measure time with Python's [time module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html). You could do something like the following:

```
import time

t = time.clock()
deltaT = 1 #time between updates, in seconds
while True: #inside the game loop...
    if (time.clock() - t) > deltaT:
        #change your image
        t = time.clock()
```

Although if you're animating sprites, you might have better luck looking for animation modules for pygame.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
import time, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg']
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 1280))
i = 0

x = time.time()

while True:
    screen.blit(images[i]) #Create the image, this syntax is wrong
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    if i != 3:
        i+=1
    elif i == 4:
        i = 0
```

Comment: Isn't `i` just going to get stuck at 3 in your code? I'd just have it as `if i < 4:`