# Space Invaders - Pygame - Random Shoot

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am making the game Space Invaders in Pygame and I want to let the enemy shoot randomly at the player. At this moment I can only let the enemy shoot at the player by pressing the tab button. But it should do this automatically and with a random interval. How can I get this working, without needing to press tab?
Thanks.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random

screenWidth = 800
screenHeight = 600
FPS = 60

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

shipWidth = 67

#colors
black=(0,0,0)
blue=(0,0, 255)
green=(0,128,0)
red=(255,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
yellow=(255,255,0)

def app_quit():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit("System exit.")

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship3.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = screenWidth / 2
        self.rect.bottom = screenHeight - 10


    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT:
            self.speedx = -2
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            self.speedx = 2
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > screenWidth:
            self.rect.right = screenWidth
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shootPlayer(self):
        bulletPlayer = BulletPlayer(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        allSprites.add(bulletPlayer)
        bulletsPlayer.add(bulletPlayer)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, 200)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(1, 2)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > screenWidth:
            self.rect.x = 0
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, 250)
            self.speedx = random.randrange(1, 3)
        # if self.rect.x > screenWidth: #kill when of the screen
        #     self.kill()

    def shootEnemy(self):
         bulletEnemy = BulletEnemy(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.bottom)
         allSprites.add(bulletEnemy)
         bulletsEnemy.add(bulletEnemy)

class BulletPlayer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -3

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

class BulletEnemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bulletenemy.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = 2

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom > screenHeight:
            self.kill()

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("wall.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = 100, 300

allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
enemy = pygame.sprite.Group()
bulletsPlayer = pygame.sprite.Group()
bulletsEnemy = pygame.sprite.Group()
wall = Wall()
allSprites.add(player, enemy, bulletsPlayer, bulletsEnemy, wall)

for i in range(1):
    e = Enemy()
    allSprites.add(e)
    enemy.add(e)

running = True
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            running = False
            app_quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shootPlayer()
            if event.key == pygame.K_TAB:
                random.choice(enemy.sprites()).shootEnemy()

    allSprites.update()

    hitplayer = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, bulletsEnemy, True)
    if hitplayer:
        running = app_quit()

    hitenemy = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemy, bulletsPlayer, True, True)
    if hitenemy:
        running = app_quit()

    screen.fill(black)
    allSprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You still up to this? I have completed what you were seeking 2 years ago -_-

Answer (score 1):

You need a random timer variable which you can decrement by the `dt` (delta time) each frame. When it's below zero, create a bullet instance, add it to the group and reset the timer. I use the [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) function here which gives you a float, but you could also use `random.randrange` or `randint` if you want ints. To get the delta time (the time since the last tick) just assign the value that `clock.tick(fps)` returns to a variable.

```
# The timer is the time in seconds until the enemy shoots.
timer = random.uniform(2, 6)  # Random float between 2 and 6.
dt = 0

running = True
while True:
    # Event handling omitted.

    # Decrease the timer by the delta time.
    timer -= dt
    if timer <= 0:  # Ready to fire.
        # Pick a random enemy to get the x and y coords.
        random_enemy = random.choice(enemy.sprites())
        enemy_x, enemy_y = random_enemy.rect.center
        # Create a bullet and add it to the sprite groups.
        bullet = BulletEnemy(enemy_x, enemy_y)
        allSprites.add(bullet)
        enemy.add(bullet)
        timer = random.uniform(2, 6)  # Reset the timer.

    # Collision detection and drawing omitted.

    # clock.tick returns the time that has passed since the last frame.
    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000  # / 1000 to convert it to seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create a custom event and trigger it based off some conditions, such as time.

You can use `pygame.event.Event()` and `pygame.event.post()` to trigger an event manually instead of using the Tab key. To setup this event on time you can use `pygame.time.set_timer(myEvent, time)`. After that your main loop just needs to check for the event with `pygame.event.get()`.

There is a good example of how to use custom events in pygame here: [PyGame Custom Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475718/pygame-custom-event)

The author's example is even a Space Invaders type game so it will be useful to look at how it is written.