# Call a sibling class' method

Tags: python, class

I am trying to call a method in another object of a class to invoke a gamer restart.

At the moment in the ball class; which will call its own restart class if the ball goes out of bounds

```
class Ball(Entity): 
    def restart(self):
        self.ball.x = self.ball_starting_spot[0]
        self.ball.y = self.ball_starting_spot[1]
        # This is where I want to call the player class restart method
```

The player class has its own `restart` method that will have to be called to reset itself. Both classes have the same `Entity` base class.

How would I get about this efficiently?

Comment: already answered on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856413/call-class-method-from-another-class

Comment: @stefan_mit_hannover Answered there, but I don't think that is a good dupe target.

Comment: Does the `Ball` have a reference to the player? If so, call `self.player.reset()`

Comment: Ball does not have a reference to player in any way, unfortunately. However I think I have found a way to do it using pygame custom event, will update whenever I try it out; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475718/pygame-custom-event

Comment: The fact that they are both derived from the same base class doesn't matter per se — they're just two different classes as far as doing what you want goes. Using a custom event might be a way to provide the needed information.

Comment: Since all classes now derive from object, all classes are in some sense sibling classes.  Unfortunately only hierarchy or reference gets you access

Comment: I eventually achieved this using pygame custom events; please read [stackoverflow.com/questions/24475718/pygame-custom-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475718/pygame-custom-event)

Comment: That's good to hear — btw you can answer your own questions here (and accept them).