# Day/night mechanic in Pygame not working

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a day/night feature for my game where every 10 minutes the background changes, but when I run it it just crashes on startup. Here's the buggy code.

```
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
bgg = pygame.image.load("bbg.png")

def bg1():
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

def bbg1():
    screen.blit(bbg, (0, 0))

def fbg():
    bg1()
    pygame.time.wait(10000)
    bbg1()


screen.fill((0,0,0))
fbg()
```

I have the screen.fill((0,0,0)) because there is a rect there as well which moves around.

Comment: The wait command freezed the execution of your app for 10 minutes.. i dont think this is what you want...

Comment: Is the 'crash' just the game waiting for 10 minutes?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839039/what-are-the-best-approaches-to-wait-some-time-in-pygame-and-python-code-in-gene

Comment: You may want to take a look here: [Move an object every few seconds in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368999/move-an-object-every-few-seconds-in-pygame)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `pygame.time.wait` call just stops the execution of the current thread for 10,000 milliseconds. You need to have another thread that actually runs the game.

The [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) states that:

> pygame.time.wait()
>
> Will pause for a given number of milliseconds. This function sleeps the process to share the processor with other programs. A program that waits for even a few milliseconds will consume very little processor time. It is slightly less accurate than the pygame.time.delay() function.