# Using a timer in pygame to fire something

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I am struggling to find a way to make a timer that can blit this image every 2 seconds. It's an image of a net and is meant to trap my player on my platform game. The net is dropped from a helicopter which I wont go into details about. At the moment the net drops once and I want it to drop continuously ever 2 seconds. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Net:
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 60
    self.height = 30
    self.velocity = 0
    self.netimage = pygame.image.load("Images/net.png")
    self.GroundCollision = False

def drop(self, heli, player, gravity):
    screen.blit(self.netimage, (self.x,self.y))
    self.velocity += gravity
    self.y += self.velocity
```

Comment: in `mainloop` call `Net.update()` which compare current time with `Net.time_to_blit_image` and after blit it sets `Net.time_to_blit_image = current_time + 2seconds`. You can use `pygame.time.get_ticks` to get current time.

Comment: or use `pygame.time.set_timer()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move an object every few seconds in Pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368999/move-an-object-every-few-seconds-in-pygame)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do with my games:

1. I create a variable called timer, and set it to 0.
2. Every loop, I check the timer variable with modulo.
3. If timer%something==0, do the thing.

It is also helpful to have a variable called "fps", in case you want to change your framerate.

Just type `timer=0` before your while loop.

Then type the following code *inside* of your while loop:

```
clock.tick(fps)
timer += 1
if timer % (fps * 2) == 0: #executes the following every 2 seconds
    Net.drop()
```

And that is all that is needed!  Have fun Pygaming!