# Pygame wait specific amount of time until something happens

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game and at the "start" screen I want it to pop up a picture after 45 seconds of not starting the game saying "Are you not going to play?"

However, I am completely lost at what to do, so if anyone have any clue on how to help that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a timer for your game, like this:

```
pygame.time.Clock.tick(fps)
```

Each time your main loop runs, it ticks your fps, so your game could run smoothly.

Now, just add a variable, called, say, `tick_counter`

Now, in your code, do something like this:

```
fps = 25
tick_counter = 0  

while RUNNING:
    #Do stuff, check for if close window, etc

    pygame.time.Clock.tick(fps)
    tick_counter += 1

    if tick_counter >= 1125: #45 seconds if you are doing 25 fps. If your fps is different, just calculate it: 45 seconds = 45*fps

        #Pop up the picture!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer and an event on the event queue. This answer shows how to do that. [How can I detect if the user has double-clicked in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918808/how-can-i-detect-if-the-user-has-double-clicked-in-pygame/36268899#36268899)