# How can I detect if user has double-tapped spacebar key in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am new to python and pygame. Can somebody help me in this please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if the user has double-clicked in pygame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918808/how-can-i-detect-if-the-user-has-double-clicked-in-pygame)

Comment: I've added another answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `tkinter`, but you can try this:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
def helloworld(event):
    print('Hello world!')
tk.bind_all('<Double-Button-1>', helloworld)
```

Sorry this uses Left Click, but I hope it answers.
You can do any code in the function, just make sure you don't use parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me.

```
global clock, double_click_event, timer
double_click_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1 
timer = 0
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       pygame.quit()
       sys.exit()
   if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
            if timer == 0:
                pygame.time.set_timer(double_click_event, 500)
                timerset = True
                x, y = pyautogui.position()
                pyautogui.click(x, y, button='left')

            else:
                if timer == 1:
                    pygame.time.set_timer(double_click_event, 0)
                    double_click()
                    timerset = False
            if timerset:
                timer = 1
            else:
                timer = 0
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work correctly. I can still double click after an arbitrary amount time. Also, what's pyautogui?

Comment: @skrx pyautogui is a automation library.